# place grid lines behind the points

Tags: d3.js

I have created a graph having the grid lines and the scatter plot. I have trouble with the grid lines because it came on top of the scatter plot. I want to place it below the scatter plot. I also know that d3.js executes statements sequentially. I have place the code for grid lines before the code for scatter plot , but it's not working. 
here's link to my graph image http://snag.gy/VEccS.jpg
below is my code.

```
var x1 = d3.scale.log()
                .range([0, width - 200])
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.PhIII_Effort; })).nice();

            var y1 = d3.scale.log()
                .range([height, 0])
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.SizeNew_1; })).nice();


            function make_x_axis1() {
                return d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x1)
                .orient("bottom")
                .ticks(5)
                }

            function make_y_axis1() {
                return d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y1)
                .orient("left")
                .ticks(5)
                }

            svg1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "grid")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(make_x_axis1()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
            );

            svg1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "grid")
            .call(make_y_axis1()
            .tickSize(-width,0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
            );
```

Comment: SVG elements are rendered in the order in which they are appended to the DOM. If your grid lines appear in front of the actual plot even though you're running the code to draw them first, you must be appending to a `g` element that has been appended after the `g` for the actual plot.